# How do I remove pipe symbol and characters inside it and trim ms and display with comma seperated

Tags: shell, sed, pipe

My String is

```
e5c1640ed000f865fb3acf675be3cda4 26/06/2018 14:43:41.935216|19*.***.***.**9| 14:45:41.971271|19*.***.***.**9|
```

Expected Output is

```
e5c1640ed000f865fb3acf675be3cda4,26/06/2018 14:43:41,26/06/2018 14:45:41
```

I tried this but it got trimmed whole set after do `cut -d. -f-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"[| .]" '{print $1","$2,$3","$2,$10}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With pure `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^\.]*\)\.\([^ ]*\) \([^\.]*\).*/\1,\2 \3,\2 \5/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E '
  s/([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)(([^|]*\|){2})(.*)/\1,\2\3,\2\5/
  s/(\.([^|]*\|){2})//g
' infile
```

First insert date and comma where needed
Second remove each strings starting with '|' and ending with '|'

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
awk -F"[ |]+" 'BEGIN {ORS=""} {
    print $1;
    dt=$2;
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) { 
      if ($i~/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+$/) {
         sub(/\..*/, "", $i);
         print "," dt " " $i;
      }
    } 
  }'
# => e5c1640ed000f865fb3acf675be3cda4,26/06/2018 14:43:41,26/06/2018 14:45:41
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nx6FFa).

It assumes the first field should always be kept, the second one is always a date that will be "repeated" before each found time value.

The field separator is `[ |]+`, 1 or more spaces or pipes. `BEGIN {ORS=""}` helps output results on a single line. `print $1;` prints the first field, `dt=$2;` saves the date to a variable, then we iterate the fields starting with the third one (`for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)`) and if a field value matches `<2-digits>:<2-digits>:<2-digits>.<1+digits>` pattern (`/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]+$/` then remove all text beginning with `.` and to the end of the value with `sub(/\..*/, "", $i);` and print the `,` + date + space and the current field value.